# 404 Error after upload PDF to document library

Tags: 2010, document-library, file-upload, pdf

I'm having an issue uploading a PDF to a document library. I've uploaded many different PDF's to many document libraries with no issues. This one PDF won't upload. I get a 404 error. It's 5 MB and opens in Reader fine. Any ideas what the issue could be? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you are trying to upload large files in SharePoint, you need to configure few settings so that you can upload larger files.

Step 1: Central Administration -> Web Application General Settings -> Edit “Maximum Upload Size”:

Step 2: Edit web.config under "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories[YourWebApplication]"

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout=”999999″ maxRequestLength=”51200″ />
```

Step 3: Edit web.config under C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

```
<location path=”upload.aspx”>
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout=”999999″ maxRequestLength=”2097151″ /> 
</system.web>
```

Step 4: Add this lines to web.config under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories[YourWebApplication] **(If you get 404 error after file upload)**

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
        <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength=”52428800″/>
        </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```